# Periodic actions in Live Wallpapers

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to make sure I'm using the most efficient/proper code in my live wallpapers. Currently if I have any periodic action I just use Runnables to repeat the action and then after it's completed postDelay it for however long it needs to be.

Is it better to only have one Runnable such as a drawFrame Runnable and just work off of that for any other periodic action?

For example:

```
int interval1 = 0;
int interval2 = 0;
drawFrame(){
  interval1++;
  interval2++;
  if (interval1==repeatInt1){
    interval1 = 0;
    // Periodic action 1
  }
  if (interval2==repeatInt2){
    interval2 = 0;
    // Periodic action 2
  }
// Regular drawFrame code here
}
```

I would think the above method would use less resources than running 3 runnables, correct?

To clarify, I have multiple actions (2 or more) that need to be executed periodically, but not necessarily all at the same delay. Would it be best to create a runnable of the shortest delay and then just use that as a central thread to execute the other actions after X amount of loops?

Answer (score 0):

Why not model the intervals using a temporal function?  If you have two actions and you want to switch between using a defined period.

```
double period = 1000;
double time = (double) System.currentTimeMillis();
if ( Math.sine( 2*Math.PI * time / period) > 0)
  //State 1: do one thing
else
  //State 2: do the other
```

There are lots of simple ways to alter the math that will allow you to control the number of states, the order in which you switch between states, and what fraction of each period is spent in each state.

Comment: I'm not really trying to figure out how to switch between actions, it's just I have maybe 3 actions that all keep repeating but at different intervals. Should I create a runnable of the shortest interval (drawFrame) and then just use it as a timer for the other two?